# Remove Last Element on List Without Ruining Bracket Formatting (Racket)

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I'm using this code to make sure the lists are put together so it will work with another function I'm writing.

```
#lang racket
(define path_from_start null)
(define path_stack null)
(define input1 '(0 0))
(define input2 '(1 2))
(define input3 '(3 1))

(define (test xy)
  (set! path_from_start (append path_from_start (list xy)))
  (display "path from start:") (display path_from_start)
  (display "\n")
  (set! path_stack (list path_from_start path_stack))
  (display "path_stack")(display path_stack)
  (display "\n")
  ;(set! path_stack (cdr path_stack))
  ;(display path_stack)
  ;(display "\n")
)

(test input1)
(test input2)
(test input3)
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
path from start:((0 0))
path_stack(((0 0)) ())
path from start:((0 0) (1 2))
path_stack(((0 0) (1 2)) (((0 0)) ()))
path from start:((0 0) (1 2) (3 1))
path_stack(((0 0) (1 2) (3 1)) (((0 0) (1 2)) (((0 0)) ())))
1st item on path_stack: '((0 0) (1 2) (3 1))
```

I don't want the empty list at the end of path_stack.  It doesn't show in path_from_start.  Its probably because of the way I'm forming path_stack.  But I want the preserve the bracket formats I have now.  Is there another variable I can initialize path_stack to?

I've looked up other methods, but they all break the bracket format.  Should I use one of those methods right at the first step?  Nip it at the bud with only 1 other element in list so I can easily reform that?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a question about arrays, you're using linked lists. I removed the "arrays" tag.

Comment: And there seems to be a problem with the brackets in `path_stack`, only the first element looks correct. See my answer, I believe that's what you meant to do in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in the second `set!` use [`list*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%2a%29%29) instead of [`list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%29%29):

```
(set! path_stack (list* path_from_start path_stack))
```

Here's the result, I believe this fixes the issues with the brackets - the sample output in the question doesn't seem correct:

```
path from start: ((0 0))
path_stack:      (((0 0)))
path from start: ((0 0) (1 2))
path_stack:      (((0 0) (1 2)) ((0 0)))
path from start: ((0 0) (1 2) (3 1))
path_stack:      (((0 0) (1 2) (3 1)) ((0 0) (1 2)) ((0 0)))
```

Now we can retrace each step in the path, like this:

```
(first path_stack)
=> '((0 0) (1 2) (3 1))
(second path_stack)
=> '((0 0) (1 2))
(third path_stack)
=> '((0 0))
```

Comment: Yeah you're right, I didnt even notice that.... list* fixed almost everything for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Great! always my pleasure :)